# Jetpack compose for desktop: run application as administrator on windows?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I am trying out Jetpack Compose for Desktop for the first time, my app require executing some external commands that requires admin privilege. How do I make the exe open as administrator when launched by the user?